# $interval's invokeApply parameter does not change anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

From the angular's [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) of $interval service:

> invokeApply (optional) boolean: If set to false skips model dirty checking, otherwise will invoke fn within the $apply block.

Which can lead us to a conclusion that $rootScope.$apply wouldn't be called if I set `invokeApply` as false.

However, from the source of $interval I learned that `deferred.notify` is called each tick, which makes sense. What does not, is the fact that during `deferred.notify` execution `$rootScope.$evalAsync` is called, which in order calls `$rootScope.$digest`. So all the dirty checking still happens. Am I missing something here?

Comment: There seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/5903)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug already filed!

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/5903

You are missing nothing